# Related Taxonomy Doesnt Show any Posts

Tags: taxonomy

Doesnt Show Any Results

```
<?php

$query = array(
    'tax_query' => array(

        'relation' => 'AND',

        array (
            'taxonomy' => 'location',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'california', '' ),
        ),

        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'genre',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'comedy', '' ),
        )
    )
);


$query = new WP_Query();


?>
```

Doesnt Show Any Results :( No Posts are displayed, Need Help thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the rest of your code looks like, but you are mixing up your `$query` variable and you are not sending your `$query` to the new instance of `WP_Query`. Also, there is no need to send an array to the "terms" parameter if you are only using one term. Try this.

```
<?php
// Set the args
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array (
            'taxonomy' => 'location',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'california',
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'genre',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'comedy',
        )
    )
);

// Make a new instance of WP_Query
$query = new WP_Query();

// Make the query
$query->query($args);

// Test for posts
if($query->have_posts())
{
    // Loop through posts
    while($query->have_posts())
    {
        // Set up the post
        $query->the_post();
        global $post;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Im getting an error Warning: Missing argument 1 for WP_Query::query(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\artwp\wp-content\themes\artwp\shows.php on line 49 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\artwp\wp-includes\query.php on line 2901

Comment: Of course you did! That's because I put the $args in the wrong place. I've updated my answer. Try it again.

Comment: i tried the code above doesnt show results also but,  when i tried

Comment: <?php $args = array(  'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND', array (  'taxonomy' => 'location',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'california',
        ), array(
            'taxonomy' => 'genre',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'comedy',
        ) ));
$query = new WP_Query($args);
$query->query('showposts=5');
if($query->have_posts())
{  while($query->have_posts()) 
    {
 echo '<div>';
  the_title();
    echo '</div>';
       $query->the_post();global $post;   }}

?> works but its showing also the posts from the post type posts

Comment: Can you pastebin your code?

Comment: Add, `'post_type' => 'your-post-type'` to the args.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all you are using it wrong.

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
     'post_type' => 'post,'
     'post_status' => 'publish',
     'tax_query' => array(
        'taxonomy' => 'genre',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array( 'comedy', '' ),
    )
));
```

The array needs to be supplied to the WP_Query object. Also, I am pretty sure atleast one post type needs to be specified for it to work.

Comment: @Chris...doesn't `post_type` default to "post" and `post_status` default to "publish". I've not tried it without setting these values, but I believe these are the defaults.

Comment: Technically they are defaults, but I have encountered situations where the query will return no results if a post_type is not specified. Post status is not required.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Set the args
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        'post_type' => 'show',
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array (
            'taxonomy' => 'location',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'california',
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'genre',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'comedy',
        )
    )
);




 // Make a new instance of WP_Query
$query = new WP_Query($args);

// Make the query
$query->query('showposts=5');

// Test for posts
if($query->have_posts())
{
    // Loop through posts
    while($query->have_posts()) 
    {
    echo '<div>';
  the_title();
    echo '</div>';

        // Set up the post
       $query->the_post();


        global $post;


    }
}



?>
```

But the problem is it shows the posts also from posts

Result: is something like
California (Comedy) Posts
Then the rest posts from the POSTS TYPE
Post1 
Post 2